# Proper format for a file name in python

Tags: python, audio, unicode, ipython, file-import

I'm importing an mp3 file using IPython (more specifically, the `IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Audio()` command) and I wanted to know if there was a specific way you were supposed to format the file path.

The documentation says it takes the file path so I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that it should be something like \home\downloads\randomfile.mp3 which I used an online converter to convert into unicode. I put that in (using, of course, `filename=u'unicode here'` but that didn't work, instead giving a bunch of errors. I tried reformatting it in different ways (just \downloads\randomfile.mp3, etc) but none of them worked. For those who are curious, here is the unicode characters: `\u005c\u0044\u006f\u0077\u006e\u006c\u006f\u0061\u0064\u0073\u005c\u0062\u0064\u0061\u0079\u0069\u006e\u0073\u0074\u0072\u0075\u006d\u0065\u006e\u0074\u002e\u006d\u0070\u0033` which translates to \home\Downloads\bdayinstrument.mp3, I believe.

So, am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to format the "file path"?

Thanks!

Comment: I just use the normal string format of the python.  In Py3 that's unicode, but no need to do any conversion.  I often use tab completion.  `file=open('part\of\path<tab>`, and gives me a list of files in that path.

Comment: What are the errors?  Show the full command you tried, along with the full error message.  One possible issue is `\b` is the escape code for a backspace.  Try a raw string `ur'\home\downloads\bdayinstrument.mp3'`.  The `r` prevents translation of escape codes.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, thank you for responding. Putting that in gave the error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'\\home\\downloads\\bdayinstrument.mp3'` which is pretty similar to what I'd been getting. It also gave an IOTraceback. If you want that, just let me know and I can add it to my question. (When I put the text of the file path in unicode, i.e., \home\ on, it gave `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'\\home\\downloads\\bdayinstrument.mp3'` plus an IOTraceback.)

Comment: If your path starts with `home`, that sounds like you're on a Unix system, like Linux. If that's the case, use forward slashes instead of backslashes: `/home/downloads/...`

Comment: Forward slashes can also be used on Windows in Python APIs, so that is a safe change for either OS.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, thank you! However, I should've mentioned, I'm on neither Linux or Windows; I just thought (again, probably incorrectly) that that was the proper way to write the command. I'm actually using a Chromebook.

Comment: Based on other questions of yours, I assume you were running this on some kind of web service and not locally on your computer, right? If that's the case, you'll have to upload your file before you can use it on the server. Please specify in your question what web service you are using.